# Exception has occurred. _ClientSocketException (ClientException with SocketException: Connection timed out (OS Error: Connection timed out, errno =

Tags: flutter, dart, http

I'm working on a github project, trying to fix the bugs on.
When i run the code trying to retrieve the list product using this class:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:front_paye_ton_kawa/config/constants/ipadress.dart';
import 'package:front_paye_ton_kawa/models/products.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class ProductsController {
  Future<List<Products>> getAllProducts(final String token) async {
    String urlString = '$ipaddress/api/v1/products?token=$token';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(urlString));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // La requête a réussi
      var products = <Products>[];
      for (var product in json.decode(response.body)) {
        products.add(Products.fromJson(product));
```

I get the bug below,

```
Exception has occurred.
_ClientSocketException (ClientException with SocketException: Connection timed out (OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110), address = 192.168.1.67, port = 44934, uri=http://192.168.1.67:8080/api/v1/products?token=)
```

I think the problem is related to the http parsing, but i don't know how to fix or make modification to work with me.

I get the bug below,

```
Exception has occurred.
_ClientSocketException (ClientException with SocketException: Connection timed out (OS Error: Connection timed out, errno = 110), address = 192.168.1.67, port = 44934, uri=http://192.168.1.67:8080/api/v1/products?token=)
```

[URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikIia.png)

How to fix this, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I hope this is about the network. If the service is internally hosted please do check for the connection in case of externally hosted application please do check for the internet connection.

Comment: I test the API URL, i don't get result, i'm trying to work with this code isn't, i don't know if the problem is with API URL or something else. i add the screenshot of URL result.

Comment: The API service is unreachable. I recommend using the POSTMAN to test API in order to get more info.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76976070/exception-has-occurred-clientsocketexception-clientexception-with-socketexcep

Comment: I already test it with POSTMAN it works please check my second update here.